# How to use GOBLIN Maximum Flow solver

Tags: c++, goblin-graph-library

According to [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) textbook, we can use [GOBLIN](http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/) libraries for many graph algorithms. Now I tried to use the [Maximum Flow solver](http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/refman/tutorialSolvers.html#tutorialMaxFlow) of GOBLIN project in my research. However, I have difficulty finding an example of how to do it. I don't know how to create a graph in the first place. According to the documentation,

http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/refman/tutorialConstruction.html#secPlainConstruction

, when I create the following cpp file (), it recognizes TNode as a type but it does not recognize 'graph' type. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <deque>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <goblin.h>
// #include <abstractMixedGraph.h>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
cout.precision ( 1 ) ;
cout << fixed ;
////////////////////////////
graph G(TNode(0));
    TNode** subset = new TNode*[cardinality];

    for (TNode i=0;i<cardinality;++i) {
       subset[i] = new TNode[cardinality];

       for (TNode j=i+1;j<cardinality;++j) {
          subset[i][j] = G.InsertNode();

          for (TNode k=0  ;k<i;++k) G.InsertArc(subset[i][j],subset[k][j]);
          for (TNode k=i+1;k<j;++k) G.InsertArc(subset[i][j],subset[i][k]);
          for (TNode k=0  ;k<i;++k) G.InsertArc(subset[i][j],subset[k][i]);
       }
    }

    for (TNode i=0;i<cardinality;++i) delete[] subset[i];
    delete[] subset;

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing an include. Where is `goblin` installed? It looks like you should include something like `#include <goblin/globals.h>`. Or even better: `#include <goblin/abstractMixedGraph.h>`.

Comment: @pingul Thanks. I did not install `goblin`. I just copied the two folders `include` and `lib_src` to the folder where I have my C++ project. According to [this page](http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/refman/pageInstallation.html), `The core library is platform independent code. To built it without the shipped Makefile, just import all files from the lib_src and include directories...`. I already have `#include <goblin.h>` which in turn includes all header filds.